# Curious anti-commutative ring

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Has anyone seen the ring $\Lambda[x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots]/(x_i x_j - (i+1) x_0 x_{i+j})$ in some natural context?

Here $\Lambda[x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ is the (graded-)commutative algebra (either over the integers or the integers localized at 2) freely generated by elements $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ of odd homological degrees, so that $x_i x_j = - x_j x_i$. In particular, we only get $2 x_i^2 = 0$, not $x_i^2 = 0$.  I probably shouldn't write $\Lambda$ here:  in characteristic $2$ or integrally, $\Lambda$ usually adds the relation $x_i^2 = 0$.

ADDED NOTE:   In the meantime, I have found a better way of solving the problem in which this arose, so it is merely a curiosity now. I am happy to delete it if people wish.

Forgive me for posting this to 'Commutative algebra', but as a topologist,  commutative means  $x y = (-1)^{(\deg x)(\deg y)} yx$, and my $x_i$ are in odd degrees.

SECOND NOTE:  This algebra has now shown up in another context, so Vladimir's answer below has been quite useful.    Thanks to Vladimir and MO.

Comment: I’ve edited the title, although the original was much better! Hope you don’t mind.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, what is this?  Commutativity for ants?

Comment: I thought ants commute all the time (e.g. for food).

Comment: What exactly is $x_i x_j - \left(i+1\right) x_0 x_{i+j}$ quantified over? All pairs of nonnegative $i$ and $j$ ? Only those with $i < j$ ?

Comment: It is quantified over all non-negative $i$ and $j$, so, in particular, $(i+j+2) x_0 x_{i+j} = 0$.

Comment: If $x_0x_{i+j} = 0$ for all $i, j$ as in your last comment, then by the equation $x_ix_j = (i + 1)x_0x_{i+j}$ defining your ring you get that $x_ix_j = 0$ for all $i, j$ and pretty much nothing interesting is left of your ring.

Comment: That is, it is still quite interesting as an Abelian group, but the multiplication is kind of boring.

Comment: Are the variables in $\Lambda[x_0,\ldots]/(x_i x_j - (i+1x_0 x_{i+j}))$ the same as those appearing in $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}[x_0,\ldots]/(x_i x_j - x_j x_i)$ or new variables? In the first case, your ring is just $\Lambda/(x_i x_j - (i+1x_0 x_{i+j}))$, right?

Comment: @Vincent:  I pointed out that $(n+2) x_0 x_n = 0$.   It does not follow that $x_0 x_n = 0$.   As for the multiplication, $x_1^2$ in the unique element of order $2$ in the $\mathbb{Z}/4$ generated by $x_0 x_2$.  Have a look at the quotient by $(x_i : i > 2)$.   I think you'll see that this quotient has $\mathbb{Z}[x_0]/(2x_0^2)$ in it.

Comment: This "commutative" definition is depressing... a terminology destroying the use of existing terminology is counterproductive. Supercommutative does the job. Anyway the tag commutative algebra is perfectly fine since commutativity is lurking behind.

Comment: @YCor I noticed your comment, and slightly edited the sentence that may have bothered you. Essentially, a commutative algebra is an algebra over the commutative operad, and this one is just happens to be a commutative algebra in a symmetric monoidal category slightly different from the tensor category of vector spaces: it is the category of homologically graded vector spaces where the symmetric monoidal structure includes the Koszul sign rule. I am not sure that it addresses your concern, but at least it makes the story consistent - "free anti-commutative algebras" is a very confusing term.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I'm afraid you didn't edit the sentence which bothered me (I referred to the last sentence and it didn't really bother me, rather I'm bothered by the sign use of commutative, and gradings are useful even in genuine commutative algebras). It made a sentence which looked good bother me now... you're calling commutative some algebra failing to satisfy $ab=ba$ for all $a,b$. I think the edit should be reverted or changed. (I find 'free anti-commutative algebra' reasonably intuitive and not confusing). If you write "homologically commutative" or "graded-commutative" it's maybe OK.

Comment: @YCor I wrote (graded-)commutative now. "Homologically commutative" is really bad - it hints at something with a nontrivial differential that becomes commutative on the level of homology. "Free anti-commutative algebras" are completely confusing: classically speaking, it could only possibly mean the free algebra for the identity $ab=-ba$; for example, it cannot have a unit, and, if it is associative, the product of any three elements is always in $2-torsion$, since $ac=-ca$ and $bc=-cb$ implies $(ab)c=c(ab)$.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko thanks. As a user of gradings in algebras (Lie algebras, commutative algebras...), I'm quite happy that objects are allowed to be graded without imposing the sign conditions!

Comment: @YCor I completely understand. As a person who uses both kinds of gradings, occasionally at the same time (it happens a lot in homotopical algebra), I belong to the school of people who write "weight grading" for classical gradings not creating signs and "homological grading" for gradings that create signs according to the "Koszul sign rule". It's an acquired taste, I know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed this now, and I want to remark that the underlying abelian group can in fact be described very precisely. To do that, note that:

(1) the defining relations easily imply that the abelian group of elements of degree $d\ge 2$ in this algebra is certainly generated by $x_0^{d-1}x_k$, $k\ge 0$, and

(2) as discussed in the comments, there are the relations $(i+j+2)x_0x_{i+j}=0$ that follow from the defining relations and anticommutativity; effectively, these give just one relation for each $n$, namely $(n+2)x_0x_n=0$.

Now let me (inspired by typical Gröbner bases calculations) consider the following two chains of equalities:
 $$
x_ix_jx_k=(i+1)x_0x_{i+j}x_k=(i+1)(i+j+1)x_0^2x_{i+j+k}
 $$
and
 $$
x_ix_jx_k=(j+1)x_ix_0x_{j+k}=-(j+1)x_0x_ix_{j+k}=-(j+1)(i+1)x_0^2x_{i+j+k}.
 $$
They imply that 
 $$
(i+1)(i+2j+2)x_0^2x_{i+j+k}=0
 $$
for each choice of $i$ and $j$ with $i+j\le n$. In particular, if $n\ge 1$, we may take $i=n-1$, $j=1$, obtaining
 $$
n(n+3)x_0^2x_n=(n-1+1)(n-1+2+2)x_0^2x_n=0.
 $$
But $(n+2)x_0x_n=0$ implies $(n+1)(n+2)x_0^2x_n=0$, so by subtraction we see that $2x_0^2x_n=0$. Moreover, no further relations can be obtained in a similar way, because once we have the 2-torsion property, we have
 $$
(i+1)(i+2j+2)x_0^2x_n=(i+1)ix_0^2x_n=0,
 $$
since $(i+1)i$ is always even.

In fact, using a version of Gröbner bases (or rewriting systems) for ideals in free anticommutative algebras, one can see that the system of all the defining relations thus obtained, namely
 $$
\begin{cases}
x_ix_j=(i+1)x_0x_{i+j},\\
(n+2)x_0x_n=0,\\
2x_0^2x_n=0
\end{cases}
 $$
is complete, and so your ring as an abelian group :

is freely generated by $1$ in degree $0$,

is freely generated by $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ in degree $1$,

is the product of cyclic groups of orders $2,3,\ldots$ generated by $x_0^2, x_0x_1, x_0x_2, \ldots$ respectively in degree $2$,

is a product of countably many cyclic groups of order $2$ generated by $x_0^d, x_0^{d-1}x_1, x_0^{d-1}x_2, \ldots$ in each degree $d\ge 3$ .